# Calling a function in the main process from the renderer

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm looking for simple tutorial/example that shows how to call a function running in the electron main process. I have this accessible to my main process:

```
//main process
exports.getDir = function() {
   var fs = require('fs')
   var contents = fs.readFileSync('hello.txt').toString();
   return contents
};
```

And this in my renderer process:

```
///
var dir = require("remote").require("./getDir");
console.log(dir)
```

This returns an object, so I think the call is working, however I can't see the file contents.

UPDATE

It seems that I should probably be using `ipcRenderer`and `ipcMain` instead. Which I'm able to get working.

Answer (score 1):

You have solved this by now, i suppose. If not this is probably what you had in mind:

```
global.getFile = function(f) {
   var fs = require('fs')
   var contents = fs.readFileSync(f).toString();
   return contents
}
```

and

```
let fnc = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('getFile')
console.log(fnc)
console.log(fnc('hello.txt'))
```